# Access Denied Error when using Cloudfront with Signed Cookies

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

I know this topic has been asked and answered multiple times all over the internet but unfortunately I'm still having issues although trying basically every single related post out there!

#### My setup

I have an **S3 bucket** with video files for a **frontend streaming service**. The files get served via a **CloudFront Distribution** and in order to secure the file access, I have set up an **API Gateway** which redirect requests to a **Custom Lambda** to get my **Signed Cookies** for CloudFront.

However, tests for the individual services were all successful:

- Setting S3 access permissions to **public** and requesting the `*.m3u8`video manifest directly from the S3 works as expected *(stream works like a charm).*
- After setting up a **custom SSL certificate** for my Cloudfront distribution *(to avoid CORS)*, and requesting the same file via CloudFront also works.
- Since my frontend needs access to an **entire folder** on the S3 *(for streaming)*, the only way - at least as I understood - is to use signed cookies for the request. Therefore, I have set up a **Custom Lambda** which returns the `Set-Cookie` headers for the CloudFront domain.
- For returning **custom headers**, we need to set up an **API Gateway** and link it to the lambda.

> I want to emphasise, that **S3**, **CloudFront**, **Lambda** and the **API Gateway** are working individually but only as long as I don't attach the cookies to the request!

So my guess is that something is wrong with the signing of the cookies.

##### Custom Lambda

Since the lambda is the source of truth for cookie signing, I will show a minimal example of what I'm doing here. My lambda is written in `Node JS` and I'm using `"@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer": "^3.229.0",`.

```js
const url = `https://my-cloudfront.domian.com/path-to-src/*`;
const expTime = new Date(Date.now() + 5 * (60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString();

const signedCookie = getSignedCookies({
  keyPairId: awsCloudfrontKeyPairId,    // from CloudFront setup
  privateKey: awsCloudfrontPrivateKey,  // from CloudFront setup
  url: url,
  dateLessThan: getExpTime,
});

const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  isBase64Encoded: false,
  body: JSON.stringify({ url: url, bucket: bucket, key: key }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
  },
  multiValueHeaders: {
    "Set-Cookie": [
      `CloudFront-Expires=${signedCookie["CloudFront-Expires"]}; Domain=domain.com; Path=/*`,
      `CloudFront-Signature=${signedCookie["CloudFront-Signature"]}; Domain=domain.com; Path=/*`,
      `CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=${signedCookie["CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id"]}; Domain=domain.com; Path=/*`,
    ],
  },
};

callback(null, response);
```

This works, I get the 3 `Set-Cookie` headers which also get submitted when requesting the file. However, the result is always the same:

```
ACCESS DENIED
```

##### Tests

To test the individual services I did the following:

- S3 only --> stream works
- CloudFront without `viewer restriction` --> stream works
- CloudFront with `viewer restriction` but **no cookies** --> `Missing Key` error
- CloudFront with `viewer restriction` and cookies --> `Access Denied` error

There obviously is a lot more important setup steps *(e.g. bucket policies, custom domains, etc)*, which I did not mention here but can be posted on request if necessary.

This topic keeps me busy since a month now! Any help appreciated!

Comment: Since this question is related, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255739/cloudfront-malformed-policy-error-with-aws-cloudfront-signer-v3) is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it's pretty embarrassing...

My above example signs cookies via a **[Custom Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html)** but uses the `Set-Cookie` header keys from a **[Canned Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html)**. The difference in the docs is not really obvious but its clearly there...

However, instead of

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Expires= ...
```

you  use

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Policy=<your policy string>
```

The keys

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Expires= ...
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Signature= ...
```

are identical.

Hope this helps!