# Cloudfront Malformed Policy Error with AWS Cloudfront-Signer V3

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I'm having an issue with the **AWS Cookie-Signer V3** and **Custom Policies**. I'm currently using `@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer v3.254.0`. I have followed the official docs of how to create and handle signed cookies - it works as long as I don't use custom policies.

#### Setup

I use a custom lambda via an API Gateway to obtain the `Set-Cookie` header with my signed cookies. These cookies will be attached to a further file-request via my AWS Cloudfront instance. In order to avoid CORS errors, I have set up custom domains for the API Gateway as well as for the Cloudfront instance.

A minified example of the signing and the return value looks as follows:

```js
// Expiration time
const getExpTime = new Date(Date.now() + 5 * (60 * 60 * 1000)).toISOString();

// Cookie-Signer
const signedCookie = getSignedCookies({
  keyPairId: "MY-KEYPAIR-ID",
  privateKey: "MY-PRIVATE-KEY",
  url: "https://cloudfront.example.com/path-to-file/file.m3u8",
  dateLessThan: getExpTime,
});

// Response
const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  isBase64Encoded: false,
  body: JSON.stringify({ url: url, bucket: bucket, key: key }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET",
  },
  multiValueHeaders: {
    "Set-Cookie": [
      `CloudFront-Expires=${signedCookie["CloudFront-Expires"]}; Domain=example.com; Path=/${path}/`,
      `CloudFront-Signature=${signedCookie["CloudFront-Signature"]}; Domain=example.com; Path=/${path}/`,
      `CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=${signedCookie["CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id"]}; Domain=example.com; Path=/${path}/`,
    ],
  },
};
```

This works well if I request **a single file** from my S3 bucket. However, since I want to stream video files from my S3 via Cloudfront and according to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html), **wildcard characters** are only allowed with **Custom Policies**. I need this wildcard to give access to the entire video folder with my video chunks. Again following the official docs, I have updated my lambda with:

```js
// Expiration time
const getExpTime = new Date(Date.now() + 5 * (60 * 60 * 1000)).getTime();

// Custom Policy
const policyString = JSON.stringify({
  Statement: [
    {
      Resource: "https://cloudfront.example.com/path-to-file/*",
      Condition: {
        DateLessThan: { "AWS:EpochTime": getExpTime },
      },
    },
  ],
});

// Cookie signing
const signedCookie = getSignedCookies({
  keyPairId: "MY-KEYPAIR-ID",
  privateKey: "MY-PRIVATE-KEY",
  policy: policyString,
  url: "https://cloudfront.example.com/path-to-file/*",
});
```

which results in a `Malformed Policy` error.

What confuses me is that the `getSignedCookies()` method requires the `url` property even though I'm using a custom policy with the `Ressource` parameter. Since the Resource parameter is optional, I've also tried without which led to the same error.

To rule out that something is wrong with the wildcard character, I've also run a test where I've pointed to the exact file but using the custom policy. Although this works **without** custom policy, it does fail with the `Malformed Policy` error when using the custom policy.

Since there is also no example of how to use the `Cloudfront Cookie-Signer V3` with custom policies, I'd be very grateful if someone can tell me how I'm supposed to type this out!

Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution and it's pretty embarrassing...

My above example signs cookies via a **[Custom Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html)** but uses the `Set-Cookie` header keys from a **[Canned Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html)**. The difference in the docs is not really obvious but its clearly there...

However, instead of

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Expires= ...
```

you  use

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Policy=<your policy string>
```

The keys

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Expires= ...
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Signature= ...
```

are identical.

Hope this helps!